# Does swing support *.ico files?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons

Setting an image for a swing action :

```
Action action = ...
// ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icon.ico"));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icon_16x16.png"));
action.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icon);
```

`*.ico` files do not get rendered, only png/jpg.
Is this by design ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The supported types might change by manufacturer and version, though you can usually count on PNG, JPG & GIF.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class QuickTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] types = ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes();
        System.out.println("This JRE supports image types:");
        for (String type : types) {
            System.out.println("Type: " + type);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output here/now

```
This JRE supports image types:
Type: bmp
Type: jpg
Type: wbmp
Type: jpeg
Type: png
Type: gif
```

Comment: I just ran this test with Oracle Java 8u74 and it still supports only these 6 formats.

Comment: @RAnders00 The support for image types is not great in J2SE, and note that it might be different on another OS (so don't presume that set is a 'given'). OTOH add JAI to the run-time class-path and that list should not only be significantly longer, but also more consistent across OS'.

Answer (score 8):

Natively, no.

How ever, you may like to take a look at [image4j](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/) which provides (IMHO) excellent support for them

Comment: It's sad. `ico` files allow you to use different, more suitable, image for different resolution.

Comment: @TomášZato Probably, but both Windows and MacOS have there own icon formats :P. There are also libraries which allow you to use SVG a (vector) images, but you'd need to dig around to find those