# Using an icon image for a GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, icons

I have created the following code for a school project, a "password protector", just for fun, really. However, the problem I have is that the icon image does not appear, but instead the default java "coffee cup".

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class UserInterfaceGUI extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    private JLabel userNameInfo; // ... more unimportant vars.

    public UserInterfaceGUI()
    {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        userNameInfo = new JLabel("Enter Username:"); // ... more unimportant var. declartions

        this.add(userNameInfo); // ... more unimportant ".add"s

        event e = new event();
        submit.addActionListener(e);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //This icon has a problem \/
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("[File Location hidden for privacy]/icon.ico");

        UserInterfaceGUI gui = new UserInterfaceGUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(400, 140);
        gui.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        gui.setTitle("Password Protector");
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why this just shows the java coffee cup at the bottom of the screen and on the bar at the top of the window?

Comment: Not sure if java can read an ".ico" file. Try using a .jpg or .gif image.

Comment: Are you sure your ImageIcon is fully initialized (error on path?) @camickr you're right , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185768/does-swing-support-ico-files

Comment: This is not going to solve your problem, but consider using [`setIconImages`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages-java.util.List-) instead, which allows to define images of different resolutions

Comment: Let me know the file is resource or in a folder out of project? Also the file you use must be smaller than "32*32" i think..

Comment: @crAlexander *"Also the file you use must be smaller than "32*32" i think."*  [Think again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224184/sizes-of-frame-icons-used-in-swing).  The icon size on some Windows machines reaches at least 40x40.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two likely problems here:

1. Java is unlikely to support .ico files.  The only types that can be relied on are GIF, PNG & JPEG.  
   For all types supported on any specific JRE, use `ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes()` (but seriously, for app. icons stick to the 3 types with guaranteed support).
2. The code is trying to load an application resource as a file, when it will likely be (or become) an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) that should be accessed by URL.  See the [embedded resource info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for tips on how to form the URL.